# One-time alert keeps executing

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to get a one-time alert when a user visits a website, then place a cookie so they're not annoyed with it every time they come back to the site. The cookie is saved and the alert executing, but it KEEPS executing and I'm tearing my hair out.

I've tried a number of things found on the web (StackExchange, how I love thee) but none seem to work. Here's the current state:

```
<script>
    function setCookie(name, value, days)
    {
      if (days)
      {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+days*24*60*60*1000);
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
      }
      else
        var expires = "";
      document.cookie = name+"=" + value+expires + ";path=/";
    }
</script>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(!setCookie('testcookie')) {
           alert("hello world");
           setCookie('testcookie','1',3);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Looking at the cookie records, it seems to be setting every time. If I change the expiration date in the script, it changes in the dev console every time. Not sure if that's indicative of the problem or not.

**===== END SOLUTION ======**

I was missing the getCookie call. I also realized that when trying to add it to the header scripts, the execution needed to be it's own function * facepalm *. I also added all the scripts to the header and instead call the function in the body tag.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function setCookie(name, value, days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+days*24*60*60*1000);
                var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }   
            else 
                var expires = "";
                document.cookie = name+"=" + value+expires + ";path=/";
        }

        var getCookie = function (c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        };

        function checkCookie() {
            if(!getCookie('testcookie2')) {
                alert("hello world");
                setCookie('testcookie2','1',3);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
```

TA-DA!

Comment: You're always setting the cookie but not querying any existing cookies.

Comment: ftr w3schools has a lot of bad information, including seemingly decent bad information, do not consider them a reliable source.

Comment: yeah, i've found it's a good place to start, but often they omit small details that make a huge difference when learning, or don't have enough variation of examples to actually help solve your problem. this forum has proven to be invaluable, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a little javascript function sometimes to retrieve cookies

```
var getCookie = function (c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
};
```

you can use this in conjunction with your other logic

```
if(!getCookie('testcookie')) {
    alert("hello world");
    setCookie('testcookie','1',3);
}
```

Comment: I thought I should also mention, I got this function from the w3Schools site: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp. There are also sample functions there for setCookie(), getCookie() and checkCookie().

Comment: Thanks, this has helped get me *almost* there. My trouble with the w3Schools example is that it adds a value (the username) and checks both. But my alert wil just be an "okay" box, so there's no value to check for. When I remove that bit, the cookie doesn't seem to set. Using my original `!getCookie` function didn't seem to work either. In that case it set every time.

Comment: Nevermind, i got it! I'll update my question with the final solution for those who need more exact answers. Thanks so much!